# META DATA in Database backup-Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

After restored a database backup, what are information retained with the DB backup other than data indexes and constraints.

1. Will there be any statistics? about table, about stored
   procedure?
2. Execution plan of stored procedure?
3. Anything else?

Environment: Sql Server 2008 RC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables Statistics, restored but all execution plan clear and cached each time executed stored procedure.